# Installing Windows 10 only on late 2009 Macbook with 32gb ssd?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Bootcamp says there isn't enough space to create the partition (must have 28gb), but there would be enough without MacOS.

Also, when removing all the MacOS Partitions with the Windows 10 Installer USB and finishing the install, I can get windows running, but it fails to boot again, always going to the windows recovery.

Comment: Warning that sharing a 32gb hard disk between two OS's is going to be *very* painful.  I would attempt to upgrade that disk if even remotely possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a windows 10 dvd use it instead and install bootcamp support from Apple's website later. Partition the drive with a bootable mac os installer (dvd or usb) to GUID partition map and Mac os Extended. Then format it as MS-DOS. Restart the computer with the windows 10 dvd if you have one (else use the usb drive, i guess). Delete the partition and then create a new partition with the windows installer. Proceed until installed. You may be able to install bootcamp support software from the USB Drive if you hunt for it. If not go to [bootcamp 5:](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1721?locale=en_US) https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1721?locale=en_US
(Windows 10 not officially supported on late 09' macbook)